# How to create a jittering overlay with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I just found this video on the YouTube, where there is a split screen with a moving grid. I want to know how to create a moving split screen just like in the video, using ffmpeg.

[Link to video](https://youtu.be/r9OMOyD4Rj8)

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

---

You seem to misunderstand me, I researched the video code on this one
My problem is that I do not know the png loop like that video.

```
    ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i nen.png  -filter_complex "overlay=x=0:y='if(gte(t,0), -w+(t)*800, 3)'" out.mp4
```

[image: Illustration]

I've tried:`loop -1 and overlay:shortest=1`but failed

Can you loop the overlay for me?

Comment: you want a split screen of 3 videos? or you want a moving split screen? or you want a split screen with borders? Anyway, get started using splitscreen here:

Comment: I want a moving split screen just like in the video.
Thank you. @Harry

Comment: You might want to edit your question to define your requirements. It would take weeks to develop an ffmpeg command that does exactly this. The split screen in the video shows: 3 videos, 2 on top and one bottom. Center split moves up and down about 5% in 3 seconds. Border is consisting of a custom but static image and borders are about 2% size. Videos are not resized but only the active area changes when the middle line moves. The video shows much more requirements. Can you limit it to a subset of all those requirements?

Comment: Then I want to make center split moves up and down about 5% in 3 seconds.Can you do that, @Harry ? I tried to test with ffmpeg and couldn't firgure the code to made it moves like that

Comment: @Harry It doesn't take weeks, really, but I agree that the question shows zero effort. It's just the grid that moves, not the split point between the videos. Passionato, next time asking for something, please show what you've tried already.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a complex filter:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i "\
movie=input-1.mp4,scale=960:540[v1]; \
movie=input-2.mp4,scale=960:540[v2]; \
movie=input-3.mp4,scale=1920:540[v3]; \
[v1][v2]hstack[hstack]; \
[hstack][v3]vstack[stack]; \
movie=grid.png[grid]; \
[stack][grid]overlay=y='5*sin(0.1*n)'[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" \
output.mp4
```

This assumes that you have three input videos (`input-1.mp4` through `input-3.mp4`), which are [`scale`d](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1) in this example just to get them to the right dimensions for the grid. They are then horizontally and [vertically `stack`ed](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) on top of each other to get a 1920⨉1080 output video labeled as `stack`.

Now you have a `grid.png` transparent overlay whose size must be 1920⨉1080 as well. Of course you have to create this grid yourself with some image editor.

This grid will be [`overlay`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1)ed on top of the stack, but its `y` coordinates will vary based on the output of [a sine function](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation). You can adjust the speed of the motion by changing the parameter before `n` (which is the number of the frame), and the amplitude by changing the parameter before the `sin` function.

Of course, if you want a more random motion, you can additionally modify the position using the `random` function, for example.

Comment: This doesn't exactly do what's in the reference. When the frame moves up,  all areas below the median chord should be masked out so that no portion of the top two quadrant videos appear below the chord.

Comment: @Mulvya But they do appear there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KRZN.png

Comment: Ah, the OP says they want "*moving split screen*", but the sample isn't actually splitting the underlying videos. Confusing because the peak amplitude varies.